# Calling preventSilentAccess will kill the browser based on chromium engine(Chrome , edge)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Im deploying signout method for my asp.net application. this my js code block :

```
$(document).on('click', '.button-logout', function () {
    dialog.confirm(translate('Warning'), translate('LoggedOutAccount'), async dialogResult => {
        debugger;
        if (dialogResult == true) {
            if (navigator.credentials && typeof PasswordCredential !== 'undefined') {
                loadPanel.indicatorShow();
                try {
                    await navigator?.credentials?.preventSilentAccess();
                } catch (e) {
                    debugger;
                }
                loadPanel.indicatorHide();
            }
            location.replace('/logout');
        }
    });
});
```

When im hitting the button it should first signout from chrome and then calls my backend controller.

problem is it forcely closes my browser without any warning even if i have multiple tabs.

This only happen in chrome and edge(firefox works without problem).